# Where to load controller dependency classes?

Tags: php, dependency-injection, controller

I'm making my own primitive MVC framework with PHP, and I'm wondering where I should load/instantiate corresponding controller dependencies?

**In the constructor of each controller (tightly coupled) or inject them (loosely coupled)?**

The only part of the latter that I'm not too sure of is for the dependencies to be instantiated on bootstrap level, outside of the MVC paradigm, before being injected. Not every controller uses the exact same dependencies besides the default parent ones. I would have to instantiate them all, which would also create a lot of overhead.

I've seen some existing frameworks do it like `$this->load->model('model'); // CodeIgniter` in the constructor, but I have no clue on why they're doing it like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest you inject the dependencies, so your controllers are less coupled to your framework. This will make a switch to another framework easier.

About instantiating dependencies: I suggest you use (or implement) a [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) container. This container should contain [factories](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) that can instantiate services.

In an ideal situation your controllers are services too (meaning they too have factories in the dependency injection container).

This way only the controller you need for a particular request will be instantiated, and therefor only its dependencies are instantiated.
When building you own framework, this means that after the routing phase (when the correct controller is known), the framework should grab that controller from the container. The container itself will make sure all dependencies that are needed will be provided.

Have a look at [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) for an example of a simple dependency injection container.

PS: That line from CodeIgniter looks a lot like the [service locator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern). This pattern is similar to [dependency injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), but does not provide *full* [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control).

Comment: Which would mean injecting them on bootstrap level into the controller, right?

Comment: Not really: You would set up the dependency injection container in the bootstrap phase (but that's just creating factories). Instantiating of services (to inject them into other services) is done by those factories at the moment you request a service from the dependency injection container. So instantiating of services is done on demand, and entirely managed by the dependency injection container.

Comment: @JasperN.Brouwer Sorry I tagged the wrong person. I mean any popular framework using controllers as a service and a dependency injection container to instantiate the controllers. Any framework that implements its controllers as a service. I have built an MVC framework and I would like to improve it with better design. I liked your answer and hence I am curious if there are some light frameworks (if possible) or any framework that does this?

Comment: @Shikhar Subedi [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) (a micro framework) can do this, take a look at their [ServiceControllerServiceProvider](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/providers/service_controller.html).

Answer (score 1):

**Q: Where should i load/instantiate corresponding controller dependencies?**

There are multiple ways.
The load and instantiation concepts are basically "before/outside" and "after/inside".

**Before and outside** means, that you load the file containing a class (which you want to instantiate and pass to the controller), before you load the controller.
But how do you know, what the controller needs, before loading the controller? Uh..

- Dependency Description Files

A description file comes into play, describing the wiring between your controller and it's dependencies. In other words, you can see the dependencies of your controller by looking at it's dependency description file. This concept is often used by Dependency Injection tools, which analyze the object and pull the dependencies names out automatically. It's also possible to maintain such a wiring configuration file manually. But it's tedious.

- Service Locator

A Service Locator is a instantiation helper for dependencies.
Basically, it contains the same information like a dependency description file, but this time in form of a `registry`. The link between parts of your application becomes this registry.

Both strategies introduce overhead. It's a trade-off. When you change the perspective and look at things from an application with maybe 500+ classes, then you realize that a dependency injection tool is sometimes worth it.

- Manual Injection

via Constructor Injection.

**After and inside** means, that you load the file containing your controller and then start to care about the dependencies.

At this point the class is not instantiated, yet, but the autoloader might do it's dirty deeds behind the scene. He evaluates the `use` statements at the top of your controller file. The `use` statements declare namespaced classes, which the autoloader resolves to actuall files and loads them. You might then start to use these classes as dependencies in your controller. *This is probably the easiest way to solve your problem and i strongly suggest looking into the topics autoloading with namespaces and use-statements.*

When the class is instantiated, you have the following possiblities:
use might use Setter Injection or Reference Injection to set the dependencies to the object. This requires that your Constructor Dependencies are already solved or your constructor is empty. 
It's possible to combine these strategies.

**Q: What does this do `$this->load->model('model'); // CodeIgniter`?**

CodeIgniter is a legacy application framework. It was created in times, when namespaced autoloading wasn't available. `$this->load` is a basic class loading helper. This is the opposite of an "auto"loader, (which surprise, surprise) loads things automatically.

CodeIgniters loader class is used to load various other classes, like libraries or files from the view, helpers, models or user defined stuff. This is again the concept of a registry. Here the registry just knowns where things are in your application layout and resolves them. So `$this->load->model('model');` means that the `model`function must have some piecies of information, about the position of model files in your application.
You provide a model name and the path for the file is constructed by `model`.
And this is exaclty what it does (except a bit of overhead): https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Loader.php#L223.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm a Symfony developer, I can only give you a reference to Symfony. 
I think you should do like they are doing in Symfony by thinking about what you need in each 
Controller object.

At least, you need :

- a Request object
- and a Model loader object that gives you every Model you need.

Create a BaseController that implements these few functions and then extend it with custom Controllers.
You can also take a look on Silex : http://silex.sensiolabs.org/ a Micro Framework

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

When do you say "In the constructor" you mean to pass in the *conatiner* and pull the dependencies from them (in the constructor)?

```
<?php

class SomeController
{
  public function __construct($container)
  {
    $this->service1 = $contanier->get('service1);
  }
  //...
}
```

**I advice against that**, though simpler and easier you will be coupling your controllers to the *container* thus using a ServiceLocator instead of truly inversion of control.

If you want your controllers to be easy unit-testable you should use inversion of control:

```
class SomeController
{
  public function __construct($service1)
  {
    $this->service1 = $service1;
  }
  //...
}
```

And you can even create your controller as a service inside the container:

```
// this uses Pimple notation, I hope you get the point
$container['controller'] = function($c) {
  return SomeController($c['service1']);
}
```

**Use proxy services to lazy load them**

Also if your controllers needs more than some services and you won't be using all of them you can:

*1) Use proxy services in order to lazy load the service only when they are really needed*

```
<?php

class ProxyService
{
  /**
   * @var Service1Type
   */
  private $actualService;

  public function __construct()
  {
    $this->actualService = null;
  }

  private function initialize()
  {
    $this->actualService = new Service1(); // This operation may take some time thus we deferred as long as possible
  }

  private function isInitialized()
  {
    return $this->actualService === null;
  }

  public function someActionOnThisService()
  {
    if (!$this->isInitalized()) {
      $this->initalize();
    }

    $this->actualService->someActionOnThisService();
  }
```

There you have a simple proxy object with lazy loading. You may want to check the fantastic [Proxy Manager Library](https://github.com/Ocramius/ProxyManager) if you want to go that route

*2) Split your controller*

If your contoller has too many dependencies, you may want to split it.

In fact you may want to read the proposal by [Paul M. Jones](http://paul-m-jones.com/) (lead developer of Aura Framework) about [MVC-Refinement](https://github.com/pmjones/mvc-refinement), IMHO is a good read even though you may not fully agree with it.

Even if you split your controller in order to reduce the dependencies, lazy loading your dependencies is a good idea (obviously you'll have to check weather if its doable in your context: more work in order to gain more speed).

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you need to define `__autoload()` function before you try to load the Classes which is not loaded yet. Like:

```
function __autoload($className) {
    require "/path/to/the/class/file/$className.php";
}
```

My example is very very simple to auto require the file which the class definition is in.
You can also use `if-else` statement or `switch` statement in that function to fit your own situations smartly.

The `__autoload()` function is called when PHP doesn't find the class definition, works for `new`, `class_exists()`, `call_user_method()`, etc, and absolutely for your dependences/parents classes. If there is still no class definition after `__autoload()` is called, PHP will generate an error.

Or you can use `spl_autoload_register()` function instead of `__autoload()` more gracefully.

For more information, you might want to see:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.autoload.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php